# How do I select certain data from API using AJAX and Axios?

Tags: javascript, ajax, axios

I want to know what I am doing wrong when selecting a URL (or any data piece) from an API using Axios. Just as an example, I would like to select the URL: ["https://media4.giphy.com/media/yy6hXyy2DsM5W/giphy-downsized.gif?cid=482277c2s3j1s8uell6vhu03111i46npv57g8yqgikgiefr8&rid=giphy-downsized.gif"](https://media4.giphy.com/media/yy6hXyy2DsM5W/giphy-downsized.gif?cid=482277c2s3j1s8uell6vhu03111i46npv57g8yqgikgiefr8&rid=giphy-downsized.gif)

from the API link: https://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?q=$puppies&api_key=MhAodEJIJxQMxW9XqxKjyXfNYdLoOIym

My HTML and Javascript is included. My function is grabbing all the API data, but it seems my `res.data[0].images.downsized.url` isn't written accurately. Any help would be much appreciated!

```js
async function getGiphs() {
    const res = await axios.get(`https://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?q=$puppies&api_key=MhAodEJIJxQMxW9XqxKjyXfNYdLoOIym`);
    console.log(res.data[0].images.downsized.url);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Giphy Party!</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <h1 class="display-4 mb-3">GIPHY Party!</h1>
    <div class="form-group">
      <form>
        <input id="search-word" class="form-control mb-3" placeholder="Enter search term">
        <button id="search-btn" class="btn btn-primary btn-md mr-2" role="button" type="submit">Search GIPHY
        <button id="remove-btn" class="btn btn-danger btn-md" role="button">Remove Images
      </form>
  </div>
<script src="giphyParty.css"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.js"></script>
<script src="giphyParty.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You exposed your API key, make sure you regenerate/reset it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
/*  i dont know see where and how you'r calling 'getGiphs' method. 
there is a small correction in accessing the results. */

async function getGiphs() {
    const res = await axios.get(`https://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?q=$puppies&api_key=MhAodEJIJxQMxW9XqxKjyXfNYdLoOIym`);
    console.log(res.data.data[0].images.downsized.url);
}
```

Comment: This makes sense now. Should have included "data" before the data[0]. Also, for clarification I was calling the function in the browser console. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add one more "data" as the returned object also has a property named "data".

```
console.log(res.data.data[0].images.downsized.url)
```